# SQL - не понятно как составить запрос

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица workers

```
+------+----------+-------+
| id   | name     | chief |
+------+----------+-------+
|    1 | Ivanov   |  NULL |
|    2 | Petrov   |     1 |
|    3 | Sidorova |     2 |
|    4 | Antonov  |  NULL |
+------+----------+-------+
```

Необходимо выбрать сотрудников, не являющихся ни чьими руководителями.

Вопрос: почему не работает запрос

```
SELECT name FROM workers WHERE chief = NULL;
```

Он выдаёт `Empty set (0.00 sec)`.

Comment: Сравнение с NULL всегда даёт NULL, который интерпретируется как FALSE. Для проверки следует использовать `WHERE chief IS NULL`

Comment: Есть! Работает! Спасибо большое!

Comment: Именно в MySQL есть специальное NULL-safe сравнение - оператор `<=>`. Т.е. формально можно использовать и `WHERE chief <=> NULL`. Но лучше не пользоваться расширениями диалекта, когда имеется стандартная конструкция, не усложняющая запрос.

Comment: Вот только ваш запрос вернет сотрудников, не являющихся ни чьими подчиненными.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как совершенно справедливо заметил Герман Борисов, Ваш исправленный запрос вернет сотрудников, не являющихся ни чьими подчиненными.

Если Вы хотите выбрать сотрудников, не являющихся ни чьими руководителями, то Вам нужен например, такой запрос:

```
SELECT name FROM workers WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT chief FROM workers WHERE chief IS NOT NULL)
```